# What does the dot signify when importing from within the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I understand from Chris Yeh's [helpful guide](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) that the dot implies "in this directory" relative to the specific module that I'm running. But given this project:

```
project/
--main.py
--lib/
​   --bar.py
​   --foo.py
```

`bar.py`:

```
class Ball:
    pass
```

`foo.py`:

```
from .bar import Ball


class SoccerBall(Ball):
    pass
```

`main.py`:

```
from lib.foo import SoccerBall

s = SoccerBall()
```

Running `main.py` works as expected.

However, if I want to run `foo.py`, I need to remove the dot from the import statement (something my IDE marks as an error):

```
from bar import Ball
```

I would expect the dot to be needed when I run `foo.py`, and for `main.py` to require the import as `from .lib.bar import Ball`. What am I missing?

```
print(sys.version)
> 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
```

Comment: Instead of you running it as a file, run it as a module?  `python3 -m lib.foo`  This answer is defined as solution 1 from @a_guest and is ideal if you are trying to fun files from within a module with dependancies across other files.

Comment: OK. It was mainly a theoretical question. My understanding is that if you run a file as `__main__`, it will not use relative imports, so you find the adjacent folder directly (without dots). If you're importing it from somewhere else, it's run as a module, so relative imports work - thus you need the dot. The IDE (PyCharm) sees that it's in a directory below top-level, so assumes it should have a dot. Thanks!